# Binding multiple versions of the same type with Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I am using Ninject to create a set of "plugins", e.g. I have:

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Class1>(); 
Bind<IFoo>().To<Class2>();
Bind<IFoo>().To<Class3>();
```

... and later on I use `kernel.GetAll<IFoo>()` and iterate over the results. Each of `Class1/Class2/Class3` implement `IFoo` of course, and have constructors that have a bunch of parameters also injected by Ninject, for example the constructor for `Class1` is **`public Class1(IBar bar, IBaz baz)`**, with both `IBar` and `IBaz` injected by Ninject. So far so good.

However, now I want to have two different "versions" of `Class1`, both bound to `IFoo`, differing only in a value passed at construction time. That is, for example, suppose the `Class1` constructor was now **`public Class1(IBar bar, IBaz baz, bool myParameter)`**, and I want to do the following:

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Class1>(); //Somehow pass 'true' to myParameter here
Bind<IFoo>().To<Class1>(); //Somehow pass 'false' to myParameter here
Bind<IFoo>().To<Class2>();
Bind<IFoo>().To<Class3>();
```

... Then, when I call `kernel.GetAll<IFoo>()`, I want 4 versions of `IFoo` returned (`Class1` "true" version, `Class1` false version, `Class2` and `Class3`). **I've read through the Ninject documentation and can't find a way to do this.**

Here are some ideas I tried, but none of them work well:

1) I could just separate classes (e.g. `Class1True` and `Class1False`), with one deriving from another, and bind to them. The problem is that this solution doesn't really scale when I have to do this for many classes - I end up polluting my class hierarchy with a lot of useless classes, and the problem becomes worse when the constructor parameter I want to pass is anything more complex than a bool. Realistic example:

```
Bind<IDrawingTool>().To<Brush>(); //Somehow pass '5' to brushThickness to create a fine brush
Bind<IDrawingTool>().To<Brush>(); //Somehow pass '25' to brushThickness to create a medium brush
Bind<IDrawingTool>().To<Brush>(); //Somehow pass '50' to brushThickness to create a coarse brush
Bind<IDrawingTool>().To<Pencil>();
Bind<IDrawingTool>().To<SprayCan>();
```

Of course, this is just one possible configuration of infinitely many possible ones. Creating a new class for each brush thickness seems wrong.

2) I looked into the possibility of using a .ToMethod binding, something like this:

```
Bind<IDrawingTool>().ToMethod(c => new Brush(5));
Bind<IDrawingTool>().ToMethod(c => new Brush(25));
Bind<IDrawingTool>().ToMethod(c => new Pencil());
```

But in this case I'm confused about the following:

a) What if the Brush() constructor actually requires other parameters as well, that must be injected via Ninject?

b) Are multiple ToMethod bindings actually allowed?

c) Would this work with InSingletonScope()?

**So to summarize: What is a good way to bind to multiple "versions" of the same type?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to create two bindings for the same type, which differ only in parameters.
So what you've got to do is:

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Class1>().WithConstructorArgument("boolParameterName", true);
Bind<IFoo>().To<Class1>().WithConstructorArgument("boolParameterName", false);
```

Use the `WithConstructorArgument` to pass the parameter. You can either have Ninject match the parameter by the name - in the above example the `Class1` ctor would need to feature a bool parameter whose name is exactly `boolParameterName`.  Or you can match the type, in which case you could only have one parameter of that type in the constructor. Example: `WithConstructorArgument(typeof(bool), true)`.
All the parameters which you don't specify by `WithConstructorArgument` get ctor-inject "as usual".

---

Complete working example (using xunit and FluentAssertions nuget packages):

```
public interface IBar { }
public class Bar : IBar { }

public interface IFoo { }

class Foo1 : IFoo
{
    public Foo1(IBar bar) { }
}

class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    public Foo2(IBar bar, bool theParametersName) { }
}

    [Fact]
    public void FactMethodName()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IBar>().To<Bar>();
        kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo1>();
        kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo2>().WithConstructorArgument("theParametersName", true);
        kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo2>().WithConstructorArgument("theParametersName", false);

        List<IFoo> foos = kernel.GetAll<IFoo>().ToList();

        foos.Should().HaveCount(3);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use any conditional bindings, resolving those "multiple versions" at runtime when the container detects a dependency will result in an exception, due to ambiguity. It surely could work in a "service-locator"-based access, but in true DI composing the object graph, you'll run into trouble using this approach.

In your depicted scenario, this ambiguity would arise should the following hypothetical situation existed:

```
public class MyDraw
{
    public MyDraw(IDrawingTool drawingTool)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}

kernel.Bind<IDrawingTool>().ToMethod(c => new Brush(5));
kernel.Bind<IDrawingTool>().ToMethod(c => new Brush(25));
kernel.Bind<IDrawingTool>().ToMethod(c => new Pencil);

// Runtime exception due to ambiguity: How would the container know which drawing tool to use?
var md = container.Get<MyDraw>();
```

However, if you have this class to be injected:

```
public class MyDraw
{
    public MyDraw(IEnumerable<IDrawingTool> allTools)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

This would work due to **multi-injection**. The caontainer would simply invoke all bindings that match `IDrawingTool`. In this case, multiple bindings are allowed, even `ToMethod(...)` ones.

What you need to do is rely upon mechanisms such as **Named Bindings** or **Contextual Bindings** (using `WhenXXX(...)` syntax, to let the **target** of injection to determine which concrete implementation it requires. Ninject has extensive support for this and actually is one of the defining features for it's core DI Framework. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding).

Comment: I always use multi-injection (via kernel.GetAll<T>) on that particular interface. However, you didn't answer my actual question. You seem to be suggesting that I use the ToMethod() approach, but what about the problem that I labelled (a) in my question - what if the Brush constructor requires other parameters that must be injected - how can I then instantiate Brush inside the ToMethod()?